# Error running unit tests on azure devops with nugget coverlet.msbuild / 2.3.1

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, coverlet

When I run the dotnet test task, the tests run correctly but when generating the report file in xml format I get the following error:

> /home/adminuser/.nuget/packages/coverlet.msbuild/2.3.1/build/netstandard2.0/coverlet.msbuild.targets(17,5):
> error : Method not found: 'Void
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode,
> System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare)'.

The project configuration file (.csproj) is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.3.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="4.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Note:**
The pipeline was running fine but from one moment to the next it started generating the following error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using self-hosted agent to run the pipeline, so the command should be executed in your local environment. You can try steps below to resolve the issue:

1.[Clean the package cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), delete the `bin and obj folder` and run the dotnet test command again.

2.Update `coverlet.msbuild` package from 2.3.1 to latest 2.9.0.

**In addition:**

To generate xml report(coverage.cobertura.xml): You should use `coverlet.collector` package with command `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`.

To generate json report(coverage.json): You should use `coverlet.msbuild` package with command `dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true`.

More details check [coverlet-coverage/coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet#quick-start).

Comment: Thank you very much friend, updating the nugget to version 2.8.0 worked perfectly for me